# What causes WPF App to close

Tags: c#, wpf

I've ran into a weird bug where a WPF app is closing after the first window closes.  This has made me curious what is triggering it to close

For example this is what I was the unworking version.  After the EULAWindow would close it would shut down the application.

```
EULAWindow eula = new EULAWindow();
eula.ShowDialog();
MainMenuWindow mainWindow = new MainMenuWindow();
mainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

I thought it would open the EULA and then open the Menu window.   I've found that if I rearranged the code it will operate like expected.

For example this will fix it:

```
EULAWindow eula = new EULAWindow();
MainMenuWindow mainWindow = new MainMenuWindow();
eula.ShowDialog();
mainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

This brings me to the question of what actually is causing the application to shut down in the first situation?

Comment: Probably an unhandled exception.  Are you getting an error message of any kind?

Comment: I catch unhandled exception, there wasn't any, no error and triggers ProcessExit event just like a regular App closing.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using your second code example?

Comment: Look at `App.ShutdownMode` and try other values in `App.OnStartup`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey nothing is preventing me from using it, just wondering what is going on here.

Comment: See Yury's answer, below.

Answer (score 3):

ShowDialog() is a blocking call. So, in the first case you have single window, then show it, then let user to close it. What should an app to do once last UI window is closed? Maybe, follow to app shutdown code? I suspect so.

In the 2nd case you create two windows before the blocking inside ShowDialog(). So, once you closed the first window, there is another one that could accommodate the user, and the app is not shutting down, it just waits for the next window to be shown.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but your second paragraph could be clearer.

Comment: Ah, that's better.

Comment: Does this mean that the App class is registering all Window classes inside of it somehow?

In the first case it's closing the app after the second ShowDialog is called before the MainMenuWindow is even shown, which should be a blocking call correct?

Comment: @DamonEarl, once you're blocked inside ShowDialog, it means it is in async mode. So, main execution line is awaiting for the ShowDialog to signal it completed, same time there is a message loop pumping your keyboard and mouse input. And once you click "Close" you have "close handler" logic being executed first, then return back to awaited main execution line. In case there is the only window, app shuts down before returning to the main execution line.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using Application Startup to create my windows, it was defaulting setting the **EULAWindow** to the **Current.MainWindow**  Then keeping the **Current.ShutDownMode** as **ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose**.

When you create two windows, before calling Show or ShowDialog, it changes the shutdown mode automatically to **ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose**

I'm not certain how or where this happening, but I can tell this is the behavior that is happening upon further investigation.